# Is it better for SEO to use generic meta data that is the same for multiple pages or to omit the meta data?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, googlebot, google-image-search

Our company has developed software to create and publish posts automatically on a WordPress site. Since the posts are published automatically and the images are also saved automatically, is it good SEO practice to use generic data for each post?

For example, if I have this data for every image:

```
        title: 'My awesome image',
        alt_text: 'an image of something awesome',
        caption: 'This is the caption text',
        description: 'More explanatory information'.
```

Is this wrong? What would be the right thing to do if I don't have the budget to write  custom data for each image?
Is it better for SEO if we don't post generic data and instead remove the fields?

Comment: It is not best practice. Not necessarily wrong but you would be better off not doing anything.  What exactly is the question here? Submitting this for rewording.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better SEO to not use filler text for those image attributes, because it would not be providing any useful information, either to people who depend on screen reader software, or to bots like Googlebot.

You might consider using a manual process that prioritizes the top 50 pages (just using that number as an example) based on organic traffic potential after publishing the content. In this way you could ensure that your pages that are most likely to rank for your higher volume keywords have all the proper image data.

Answer (score 1):

You have saved that data exactly? That's not just an example of the actual values of those fields?

Remove it. Quickly. Repeating all of those fields for every image in all of your new posts is bad practice. Lacking an alt attribute is also bad practice, but it's better to have no alt attribute than the same one a hundred or thousand times.

If you don't have time to add a simple alt attribute to each image individually, how are you generating the rest of the content and how is it going to be of any use to people searching? As such, this sounds (as your question is phrased) that you're looking to game Google's search results by generating a lot of seemingly useful content, while just automatically generating dross.